# Keep getting an empty array from server for FormData sent with blob/file object

Tags: javascript, blob, form-data, web-mediarecorder

I am currently having an issue with the following code. I keep getting back an **empty array from upload.php even though I send the FormData with the .mp4 blob/file created and attached to said FormData**. It's just not clear as to why it's empty as I can even console.log the FormData object I created and clearly see that the blob/file object was added. So really not sure why the server is not getting it. I've looked far and wide to find a solution but to no avail.

**Any assistance given will be greatly appreciated guys**. Thanks in advance

```
<!--INDEX.HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Recorder in Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <video id="gum" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
      <video id="recorded" playsinline loop></video>

      <div>
        <button id="start">Start camera</button>
        <button id="record" disabled>Record</button>
        <button id="play" disabled>Play</button>
        <button id="download" disabled>Download</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Media Stream Constraints options</h4>
        <p>
          Echo cancellation: <input type="checkbox" id="echoCancellation" />
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <span id="errorMsg"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>





//SCRIPT.JS
'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
const playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');


recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recordButton.textContent === 'Record') {
    startRecording();
  } else {
    stopRecording();
    recordButton.textContent = 'Record';
    playButton.disabled = false;
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  }
});


playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  recordedVideo.src = null;
  recordedVideo.srcObject = null;
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  recordedVideo.play();
});


downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});

    const fdata = new FormData()

    var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], 'aFileName.mp4');
    fdata.append("upload", fileOfBlob);

    for (var key of fdata.entries()) {
        console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
    }
      $.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          type: 'POST',
          blob: fdata,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(data) {
              // Sent to Server
              console.log(`${data}`)
          }
      });


});


function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  console.log('handleDataAvailable', event);
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'};
  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
    console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
  };
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start();
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
}

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  recordButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream:', stream);
  window.stream = stream;

  const gumVideo = document.querySelector('video#gum');
  gumVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

async function init(constraints) {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    handleSuccess(stream);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
  }
}

document.querySelector('button#start').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const hasEchoCancellation = document.querySelector('#echoCancellation').checked;
  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: {exact: hasEchoCancellation}
    },
    //video: false   
    video : {width: 1280, height: 720}
  };
  console.log('Using media constraints:', constraints);
  await init(constraints);
});



//UPLOAD.PHP

<?php
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: What does the `Content-Type` header of the request look like, when you inspect it via dev tools?

Comment: `$.ajax({ ... blob: fdata` -> `$.ajax({ ... data: fdata`. Also, it's not because you set the `type` parameter of your file to `"mp4"` that your file is converted to mp4, it's still a *webm* video file, with a VP9 video codec and an opus audio one.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the ajax response type:

```
xhrFields: { 
    responseType: "blob" 
},
```

And change the `blob` key to `name` key.
For Example:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          type: 'POST',
          xhrFields: { 
              responseType: "blob" 
          },
          data: fdata,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(data) {
              // Sent to Server
              console.log(`${data}`)
          }
      });
```

Comment: Yes I got back a response. Thank you. However, could you please help me with how I could actually save it to a folder?

Comment: I think that will work `file_put_contents('/path/to/new/file_name.mp4', $_POST['upload']);`

Comment: And one more thing @Jori, if the answer works for you then give a +1 to mark it answered. That will help the system.

Comment: Okay will do @raik and thanks for the help thus far. I need some clarifications if you don't mind.

1. why use $_POST['upload']?
2. whenever I do if($_POST['data']) which the name of the object sent via ajax it doesn't work. Any idea why?
3. Also, how would I structure it to be saved with unique names? Thanks in advance sooo much

Comment: Of course, you can ask them here.

Comment: Please see the edits made above in case you missed it

Comment: 1 & 2. Because data is not part of the PHP parsing, php parse the FormData and see there is blob with `upload` key, 3. Get the current system time and a random integer to generate unique name every-time.

Comment: Hi again. I tried the solution you mentioned however the mp4 file is saved with zero(0) bytes. Sigh. Not sure why at all. Any suggestions? Should do any conversions or such?